# Nativescript/Angular/Javascript Error with list

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, nativescript

So basically I'm just setting up a simple workout app and when I try to print out the list of info from the list I'm storing.  This is the function that is run when the submit set button is pressed & the lift class.  I'm just storing it in a list of lifts.

```
recordSet() {
    if (this.sets >= this.count) {
        this.liftList.push(
            new lift(this.count, this.reps, this.weight, this.rpe)
        );
    }
    if (this.sets > this.count) {
        this.count++;
    } else {
        this.liftList.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element);
        });
    }
}

export class lift {
    name: string = "lift";
    set: number;
    reps: number;
    weight: number;
    rpe: number;
    constructor(set: number, reps: number, weight: number, rpe: number) {
        this.set = set;
        this.reps = reps;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.rpe = rpe;
    }
}
```

when I print it out some of it always prints the correct numbers, but the list elements are completely messed up.[This is how it is supposed to show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/themO.png) and then this is how some of the elements show up (it does not seem to be consistent as to how they are off but this is just an example) [incorrect printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQtgl.png).  I'm not sure what could be causing this.  It seems like somehow some parts of the lift are being pushed outside of an element or into the next element.

Comment: Are you using Playground Or building app locally?

Comment: I am using playground (tns preview command in terminal)

Comment: Logs could be messy in Playground, because it's sent over network the order of log could be different.

Comment: okay so is there anything I can do about that or is it just building locally that is my only option?

Comment: In my opinion it's not a big deal, when there are simultaneous / multi-line log statements only then this happens. Anyways you will have to eventually build the app locally if you want to publish. So if you like to see logs at real time, you may start build it locally.